# Getting a blank page, on deploying a react app to Github pages

Tags: html, reactjs, create-react-app, github-pages

**I'm getting a white blank page on deploying my react app to GitHub pages**

It seems like every thing is working only the react components are not able to fetch. Also i'm getting **two errors in my console** when i build my react app :
[image]

Here's my **GitHub repository** link:(https://github.com/shivam-ivam/My-Portfolio)

Here's my **index.html** code which is in public folder:

```
<!-- w3schools materials css link  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

    <title>Shivam Ivam</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

Here's my **index.js** code inside src folder:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
<>
<Navbar />
<FrontPage />
</>
);
```

Here's my **FrontPage.js** component code:

```
export default function FrontPage() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
    <div className="circle1 circle"></div>
    <div className="circle2 circle"></div>
    <div className="oval oval1"></div>
    <div className="oval oval2"></div>
    <div className="name">
      <span className="im">I'm</span>
      <div className="glitch-wrapper"></div>
      <h1 className="glitch">Shivam</h1>
      <p>A programming student</p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  )
}
```

Here's my **Navbar.js** component code:

```
export default function Navbar() {
  function openLeftMenu() {
    document.getElementById("leftMenu").style.display = "block";
  }
  
  function closeLeftMenu() {
    document.getElementById("leftMenu").style.display = "none";
  }
  return (
    <div>    <div className="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-card w3-animate-left" style={{display:'none', zIndex:10}} id="leftMenu">
    <button onClick={closeLeftMenu} className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large">Close &times;</button>
    <a href="/" className="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
    <a href="/" className="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 2</a>
    <a href="/" className="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
  </div>  
    <button className="w3-button hamberg w3-xlarge w3-left" style={{zIndex:9, position:'fixed'}} onClick={openLeftMenu}>&#9776;</button> </div>
  )
}
```

Here's my **package.json** code:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://github.com/shivam-ivam/My-Portfolio",
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**I'm getting a white blank page on deploying my react app to GitHub pages**

It seems like every thing is working only the react components are not able to fetch.
I also tried other's solutions in stack overflow but nothing worked for me.

**NOTE**: I am not using any type of router.

Answer (score 0):

Github pages require an index.html file in the **root** directory.

Try running `npm run build` and uploading those files instead.

Comment: I already tried but nothing works for me

Comment: I took a look at your github repo and the index.html file isn't in the root directory

Comment: the actual react app code is present inside the master branch. If you noticed there will be another branch named as gh-page in which the build app is present. And i am trying to publish from that branch. even in my pc the app is not working after npm run build. i.e. a blank white page appears only. Please help me.